# System of two ODE

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I need to solve

$$ 
\alpha F(x, y_0) = G(x) + y_0 + F_x(x, y_0)(H(x, F(x, y_0)) + \lambda_0 (F(x, y_{1}) - F(x, y_0)) \\
\alpha F(x, y_1) = G(x) + y_1 + F_x(x, y_1)(H(x, F(x, y_1)) + \lambda_1 (F(x, y_{0}) - F(x, y_1)) \\
$$

for $F$. $0 < \alpha < 1$, $\lambda_i > 0$; $G$ and $H$ are known and continuously differentiable. How could I proceed here? A numerical solution would be sufficient.

Here is the most simplified meaningful version of the functions:

$$ 
G(x) = (x-0.5)^2 + 0.5\\
H(x, F) = (1-x)s - x\cdot X(x, F) \\
X(x,F) = \begin{cases} (1-(k/J)^a)^\frac{1}{a} & \text{ if } k < J\\ 0 & \text{ else } \end{cases}$$

And we know that $x \in [0, 1]$.

Comment: The notation for $y$ is not clear, does it mean two values $y_0$ and $y_1$ and their inverses $1/y_0$ and $1/y_1$?

Comment: @mvw I've wrote the system explicitly, hope that clears it up.

Comment: You have two functions $f_k(x)=F(x,y_k)$ and an easily solvable formula for their derivatives. What is preventing you in applying a standard ODE solver?

Comment: @LutzL I've never done that before. I've looked into numerical solvers for Python now, but it appears they require

Comment: Could you please also indicate the format of the functions, i.e., dimensions of domain and range. It might be more complicate than an ODE.